# In the Orchard CMS, how do you make your site look at a Twitter Boostrap on a CDN instead of within the Theme folder

Tags: orchardcms, cdn, orchardcms-1.9

I am using Orchard v.1.9.1.0.

I have my custom theme with a layout page that starts off like this:

```
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;

@{
    Script.Require("ShapesBase");
    // css
    Style.Include("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");
    Style.Include("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
}
```

Using `Script.Include`, I thought loading the CDN reference would work, but when building the project and viewing it locally, the reference is not there and instead renders like this:

```
<link href="/Themes/HotToddy5K/Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Why does Orchard do this? I can't seem to find where in the base/core it's applying this. I tried to delete that bootstrap.min.css file in that "scripts" folder, hoping it would then fall back to my CDN reference, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does strictly typing https work? If both endpoints support https I would just use that even if your page is only http.

Comment: It worked! Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this on your ResourceManifest.cs.

Actually it is better, because you can provide fallbacks as for debugging files. you can manage this feature from the Settings section in the Admin.

Where is says "Resource Mode", in 1.9x you can trigger the CDN too.

I use Script/Style.Require instead of Include as it gives me more control. it also maintains your script/style dependencies.